# What is the plain Javascript equivalent of .each and $(this) when used together like in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the plain Javascript equivalent of `.each` and `$(this).find` when used together in this example?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.rows').each(function(){
        var textfield = $(this).find(".textfield");
        var colorbox = $(this).find(".box");

            function colorchange() {
                if (textfield.val() <100 || textfield.val() == null) {

                    colorbox.css("background-color","red");
                    colorbox.html("Too Low");
                    }

                else if (textfield.val() >300) {

                    colorbox.css("background-color","red");
                    colorbox.html("Too High");
                    }

                else {

                    colorbox.css("background-color","green");
                    colorbox.html("Just Right");
                    }
                }
            textfield.keyup(colorchange);
        }

)});
```

Here's a fiddle with basically what I'm trying to accomplish, I know I need to use a loop I'm just not sure exactly how to set it up.  I don't want to use jquery just for this simple functionality if I don't have to

http://jsfiddle.net/8u5dj/

I deleted the code I already tried because it changed every instance of the colorbox so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Your "example" should be part of your question.

Comment: There's really no plain JavaScript equivalent of `$(this)` - that's a jQuery idiom.

Comment: `.each` `-->` `while|for` loop

Comment: there is no need for an loop here - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E6upz/1/

Comment: The loop part isn't what I have the most problem with I suppose it's assigning the variables for each element independent of the identical elements on the page, what the equivalent of `$(this).find` would be.

Comment: Why is this on hold... how is it off topic... Jesus why do I even try to find help on this site..

Comment: I have seen literally thousands of questions that just link to a fiddle yet mine gets put on hold and downvoted....

Comment: @Muskogeee Just because someone else got away with it doesn't make it acceptable. though... i wouldn't have closed this, as it's very easy to copy code from fiddle to the question. Though, i still think it's a terrible question. you've shown no effort at doing this yourself. No research. No nothing. it's an *"icanhascodez"* question. after replacing those two lines, you'll have to also replace the majority of the rest of your code because it all also relies on jquery.

Comment: I understand you've tried things and just haven't shown them, but you need to show them. It's likely that one of your attempts came close and just need to be slightly modified, which would be much less work on us.

Comment: @KevinB I've tried plenty myself, scoured Google for a clear answer and couldn't find one. I know how to change the rest of the code myself the main thing I don't understand, as I said, is how to assign the variables for each iteration of the function.

Comment: Here's an example of using plain javascript to get the job done: http://jsfiddle.net/johnboker/6A5WS/4/

Comment: @JohnBoker Thank you, that explains what I was missing.

Comment: @KevinB This isn't an _"icanhascodez"_ question at all, I'm not even using this code for anything I'm just trying to learn, but the only thing I've learned in my experience on this site is that if you're a newbie, don't even bother coming here.

Comment: I know that wasn't your intent, but that's the way the question is presented. I'm trying to show you why that is and how to fix it so that you will have a better experience on this site going forward. For example, your code sample, if all you care about is the each and those two variables, cut the rest of the code out of the equation, it will just cause confusion, or people to turn away.

Comment: I included the code because the last time I asked a similar question, aside from being met with criticism as usual, I didn't provide a clear example of what I was trying to do... So everyone basically just said use a loop, which I already knew how to do, but that just applied the function to everything. It was having the function run independently in each div that I didn't understand.  Shame on me for not seeing that I had to use the index of the array to assign each variable, I mean I've been doing this a while week, I should really know better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to do what you want in plain javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/johnboker/6A5WS/4/

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('rows');

for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
{
    var textfield = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('textfield')[0];
    var colorbox = rows[i].getElementsByClassName('box')[0];

    var colorchange = function(tf, cb)
    { 
        return  function() 
        {
            if (tf.value < 100 || tf.value == null) 
            {
                cb.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                cb.innerText = "Too Low";
            }
            else if (tf.value > 300) 
            {
                cb.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                cb.innerText = "Too High";
            }
            else 
            {
                cb.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                cb.innerText = "Just Right";                    
            }               
        };
    }(textfield, colorbox);

    textfield.onkeyup = colorchange;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.rows');
for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    var textfield = row.querySelector('.textfield');
    var colorbox = row.querySelector('.box');
    // ...
}
```

Note that you must use a `for` loop to iterate the rows because `querySelectorAll()` does **not** return an array, despite appearances. In particular, that means that `.forEach()` isn't valid on the returned list.

Comment: This does not seem to be true (anymore).

`
document.querySelectorAll('.textfield').forEach(function(textfield) {
    console.log(textfield.value);
  })
`

works for me.